# How to test method that makes call to Repository?

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, repository, spring-data

I am new to writing Junit tests. I would like to know how I can test a method such as the below:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Dog> getAllDogs() {
        Iterable<Dog> allDogs = dogRepository.findAll();
        return Lists.newArrayList(allDogs);
    }
```

**DogRepository Class** (note findall() method is inherited)

```
public interface DogRepository extends CrudRepository<Dog, Integer> {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mock the repository, inject this mock into the service, and call the method under test.

Example with Mockito:

```
DogRepository mockRepo = mock(DogRepository.class);

Dog fido = new Dog("Fido");
Dog brutus = new Dog("Brutus");
when(mockRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(fido, brutus));

DogService service = new DogService(mockRepo);
List<Dog> result = service.getAllDogs();
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(fido, brutus), result);
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, do you have a suggestion for a good mockito resource to learn about it? Also, I have autowired the repository in the class where my method it, will this matter for the test?

Comment: The official documentation, as in most projects, is the best place to learn. If, by autowired, you mean that you're using field injection, then Mockito can help injecting a mock in that field using its Mock and InjectMocks annotations, but constructor injection is cleaner. Create a constructor taking the repo as argument and annotate it with @Autowired, instead of annotating the field.

Comment: Thank you, can you please update answer to reflect this?

Comment: Also please note that the method does not take a dogRepository as a param?

Comment: How can you assume that the service class takes argument of the repository instance?